# Syntax check tool for terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am getting the error mentioned below, but I have no clue, where is the quotes not closed. To best of my knowledge as looks well

Error message:

```
At 55:2: literal not terminated
```

Code is below:

```
resource "azurerm_network_interface" "tf-ni-erx-sqlcl2" {
 count               = "${var.count_sqlcl2_vm}"
 name                = "${var.sql_base_hostname}${format("%02d",count.index+(var.count_sqlcl1_vm)-nic01"
 location            = "${data.azurerm_resource_group.tf-rg-erx-external.location}"
 resource_group_name = "${data.azurerm_resource_group.tf-rg-erx-external.name}"

ip_configuration {
    name                          = "${var.sql_base_hostname}${format("%02d",count.index+1)}-iip01"
    subnet_id                     = "${data.azurerm_subnet.tf-sn-erx-sql.id}"
    private_ip_address_allocation = "${var.env=="msdn"?"dynamic":"static"}"
    private_ip_address            = "10.112.3.${count.index+15}"
    public_ip_address_id          = "${var.sql_base_hostname}${format("%02d",count.index+1)}-pip01"
}
}
```

terraform validate also points out error like 55:2 but nothing more in specific, how to get more information on the error?

Looks like some issue with double quotes? but unable to figure it out which one as all of them have been closed.

Comment: i dont think you can use quotes inside quotes?

Comment: It does work, it worked before, issue maybe around (var.count_sqlcl1_vm)

Comment: You're missing a closing brace on line 3. `"${var.sql_base_hostname}${format("%02d",count.index+(var.count_sqlcl1_vm)-nic01"` should be `"${var.sql_base_hostname}${format("%02d",count.index+(var.count_sqlcl1_vm)-nic01}"

Comment: Closing to vote as it's just a typo. In general you should be counting your opening/closing things or using a text editor that will do that for you.

Comment: It was not a typo, it was incorrect understanding which I now now from the reply from Charles Xu

Comment: I didn't downvote, I voted to close it as a typo because that's all it is unfortunately. It's certainly not worthy of a downvote in my mind because you showed your code to the point that it was answerable. Unfortunately questions that boil down to a typo aren't useful for others so aren't worth keeping open, hence the option to vote to close as a typo.

Comment: Ok fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the code that you provided, you need to change the name in `azurerm_network_interface` into the format like this:

```
name = "${var.sql_base_hostname}${format("%02d%s",count.index,var.count_sqlcl1_vm)}-nic01"
```

And the other one point, I suggest you use the static allocate method for all network interface if you set the property `private_ip_address`.

Comment: Hi Charles, I want to set ip address as "static"/private if there is express route and "dynamic"/public IP if there is no express route. So essentially if environment is MSDN then it should use, Dynamic, meaning Public IP. If environment is not MSDN then use private IP as then Subscription is attached else use public IP

Comment: @learner Well, if so, I think you also should make a condition for the `private_ip_address`.

Comment: private_ip_address = "${var.env=="msdn"?"":"10.112.3.${count.index+10}"}"
Would this do?

Comment: I am using it but interpolation defeats me every time!

Comment: @learner Maybe the if-statements is more appropriate. Just like `if $(var.env) {private_ip_address = "10.112.3.${count.index+10}"}`. Or take a change like `private_ip_address = "${var.env=="msdn"?":"10.112.3.${count.index+10}":"""`

Comment: So Charles as per your statement I believe you are stating Private IP if it is MSDN else not, correct? I want exactly opposite, if MSDN, then dynamic IP else static IP.
Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: @learner I know what you want. I just give a possible way to do that judgment. You can input msdn or not make the if-statement come true. It's a condition.

Comment: Ok, I try and figure it out.